# How to protect my computer from being tracked by a web site?

Tags: encryption, privacy, html

Many sites track/trace users when the visit it. What I mean by that, is  let's say I visit a page then the owner of the site sees that one person visited his site.

Is there any way to be protected from that? For example, when I get on a site the owner can't see that I visited it?

Comment: In general, you can't. The site owner controls the server, and can see that someone has visited. They might not be able to identify who visited it, but they can see that a visit occurred. Why would you want to stop someone from telling that?

Answer (score 2):

> can't see that I visited it

You can prevent an owner knowing the *you* personally visited. To do so, you need to mask your originating location. Either via something like TOR or via a VPN than changes you address on each request. You also need to mask your browser signature since that may also be used to track you. Using Incognito/InPrivate sessions, refusing cookies and other local storage and changing parameters such as local IP address, screen size, etc. - or alternatively keeping them static but at the most common possible values so that you cannot be detected from everyone else.

You cannot, of course, prevent them from knowing that *someone* visited.

Answer (score 1):

If the site is available on the Wayback Machine, or other historic caching site, and it is static and non-interactive (which is rare these days) then you could visit the historic cache of the site. The use of a pre-existing cache is the only way I could think of from getting hold of a site's content without leaving a record of *someone* visiting the site. If it's just anonymity then @Julian's answer is pretty complete.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to avoid being tracked, you could create a virtual machine and access the site only from inside it. This way your computer is virtual, and you can reset it any time, creating a new computer any time you wish.

If your intention is to not allowing the site owner to know you accessed it, you could use Google Cache, or Wayback Machine as @David said. This way you are not accessing the site directly, but using another service as a proxy.

You could use a browser for your day-to-day browsing, and another one only for sites you don't want to track you. Configure the secondary browser to delete all and any private information on exit. And use a proxy or VPN if possible. This way, every time you connect to the site, it would appear as if you were a different client, because any tracking information was wiped.